# How to call cancellation token correctly in async method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, cancellation-token

Here, I have to cancel the async method LoadStoryHtmlData() from either OnStoryChange() or eventhandler OnStoryModelPropertyChanged(). but I see when cts.Cancel(); is called my debugger doesnot hit the catch (OperationCanceledException) block. which makes me think that I have not applies cts token correctly. can you please help to correct this code block.

```
private void OnStoryChange()
        {
            _logger.Log("OnStoryChange: storyId:" + _storyModel.StoryId);
            if (cts != null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
            }
            try
            {
                if (_webBrowser != null && _webBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized)
                {
                    isJsCalled = false;
                    _webBrowser.Stop();

                    //If textData and html data are empty, the story is first to load.
                    if (_storyModel.HtmlData == null)
                    {
                        string loadingTip = string.Format("<html><b>{0}</b><br/><br/><i>Loading...</i></html>", _storyModel.Headline);

                         LoadStoryHtmlData(loadingTip);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         LoadStoryHtmlData(_storyModel.HtmlData);
                    }
                }
            }           
        }

 private void OnStoryModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {

            if (args.PropertyName.Equals("HtmlData", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var storyModel = sender as IStoryModel;
                if (storyModel != null)
                {
                    _logger.Log("OnStoryModelPropertyChanged: storyId:" + storyModel.StoryId);
                    LoadStoryHtmlData(storyModel.HtmlData);
                }
            }       
        }
private async void LoadStoryHtmlData(string text)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            _logger.Log(string.Format("LoadStoryHtmlData: starting."));
            var nonHtmlText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (BodyIsUrl(text))
                {
                    nonHtmlText = string.Format("<html><b>{0}</b><br/><br/><i>{{Content cannot be loaded.Please click on the link in release body view}}</i></html>", _storyModel.Headline);

                    if (_webBrowser != null && _webBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized)
                    {
                        // bool response = Task.Run(() => IsValidUrl(text)).Result;
                        if (await IsValidUrl(text, cts.Token))
                        {
                            _webBrowser.Load(text.Trim());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _webBrowser.LoadHtml(nonHtmlText, "http://www.reuters.com/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    text = LoadHtmlText(text);
                }
                _logger.Log(string.Format("LoadStoryHtmlData: ending. StoryId:{0}", _storyModel == null ? "" : _storyModel.StoryId));
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                _logger.Log(string.Format("Load Operation cancelled."));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                _webBrowser.Load(text.Trim());
            }
            cts = null;
        }
 public async Task<bool> IsValidUrl(string siteURL,CancellationToken ct)
        {
            try
            {
                if (siteURL.IndexOf(".xls") > 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                    Task<string> httpClient = GetContentType(siteURL.Trim());
                    var contentType = await httpClient;
                    _logger.Info("The Content type of the URL: " + siteURL + " is " + contentType);

                    if (contentType.Contains(Utility.Excel) || contentType.Contains(Utility.MsWord) || contentType.Contains(Utility.OctetStream) || contentType.Contains(Utility.OfficeDocument))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex.ToString() + " With " + siteURL.Trim());
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Basically, you need to check for the cancellation token in the method(s) that do the most of the processing. As I can guess from your code, those methods could be `LoadStoryHtmlData` and `_webBrowser.Load`/`_webBrowser.LoadHtml` ... but the token is only checked in `IsValidUrl`, wich looks like to be doing only a validation (not heavy process).

Comment: @cicher can you reform the code above and send as it's not clear to me where should I send the token from where should I cancel it.

Comment: You have to check if `_webBrowser.Load` and `_webBrowser.LoadHtml` have any overloads that receive a CancellationToker (maybe there are some `LoadASync`/`LoadHtmlAsync`), or if `_webBrowser` component has any other way to support cancellation

Comment: No those are inbuilt methods of cefsharp browser. The method which I want to cancel is LoadStoryHtmlData

Answer (score 1):

Your `CancellationToken` needs to be observed somehow.

It appears that you're doing I/O-bound work, so the proper way to observe the `CancellationToken` is to pass it down to whatever APIs you're calling to do the actual I/O.

Currently, the code is passing it to `IsValidUrl`, which then does I/O *without* passing the `CancellationToken`. You'll need to modify the code so that the `CancellationToken` is passed all the way down. In this case, you should pass it to `GetContentType`, and `GetContentType` should pass it to whatever type is doing the actual I/O (e.g., `HttpClient`).

Comment: Hey Stephen, thank you for your answer, will try if it works

Comment: Hey Stephen, I passedct in all other methods and cts.cancel() is getting called properly but the catch(operationcancellationexceltion) block is never hit. Any idea why ?

Comment: The `CancellationToken` needs to be **observed**. I suspect one of your methods is taking it as a parameter and then *not using it*.